# Microsoft Graph API - Create a user with a Microsoft account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I trying create a new user via the [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Graph) API like below.

[image]

Actually I want to log in with my Microsoft account. But I get this error. Is there a solution to this without sending an invite to the user?

[image]

Comment: This is confusing naming. There is also the Facebook *[Graph API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was an Azure AD B2C user, your approach would be partially correct.
But the issuer assigned id is not the email/username, it is a unique identifier generated by Microsoft.
And you can't really know it in advance as far as I know.
But that login page does not look like B2C, that looks like the regular Azure AD login page.

If this is a "regular" Azure AD user, then Gaurav Mantri's answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible.

A user must be the part of Azure AD with proper permissions to perform any operations (like creating users) in that Azure AD.

What you have to do is invite the user to be a part of Azure AD and assign that user appropriate roles.